# How to Calculate Compound Interest in C++?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to write a program to calculate compound interest, but I'm not sure how to use the `pow()` function. My assignment is this:

> Dvijesh makes his first $1,025.75 deposit into an IRA earning 4.125% compounded annually on his 24th birthday and his last $1,025.75 deposit on his 35th birthday. With no additional deposits, the money in the IRA continues to earn 4.125% interest compounded monthly until Dvijesh retires on his 65th birthday. Write a program to find out the amount of money that Dvijesh has in his IRA on his 35th and 65th birthday? How much interest did Dvijesh earn on his 35th and 65th birthday?
>
> FV = PMT{(1+i)^n-1 / i}
>
> A=P(1+i)^n
>
> FV:Future Value; PMT:Periodic Payment; i:Rate Per Period; n:Number Of
> Payments; A:Future Amount; P:Principal

Right now, I'm trying to calculate the first formula, and this is what I have so far:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main()
{               
    double futureValue, periodic_payment, rate_per_period;
    int n; // number of payments

    cout << "Enter the periodic payment, rate per period, and time of investment: ";
    cin >> periodic_payment >> rate_per_period >> n;

    // Future value of 35th birthday
    futureValue = periodic_payment * pow((1 + rate_per_period, n) * 0.01) / (rate_per_period));

    return 0;
}
```

We wrote something similar in my C++ class, but the formula was different. I'm not sure how to write `FV = PMT{(1+i)^n-1 / i}` in C++.

Comment: *"(1+i)^n-1"* or "(1+i)^(n-1)"?

Comment: Where did the `*0.01` come from? OK, I have a guess, but since there is no `0.01` in the original formula, you should justify (in your question) why this appears out of seemingly nowhere.

Comment: @JaMiT The previous program I wrote in class used 0.01 and I was testing things to see if this is what I needed to use instead of - 1. I replaced 0.01 with - 1 but it still has errors with the pow function.

Comment: *"The previous program I wrote in class used 0.01"* -- I don't doubt that, but you should understand why it used 0.01 before tossing it into a new program. This is just a guess since you did not say what the expected input was (or, better, hard code values instead of getting user input for this example), but probably you are expecting the user to enter something like `3.0` meaning "3.0%", which needs to be converted to the non-percentage `0.03`. If that's the case, a less error-prone approach is to convert `rate_per_period` before applying the formula.

Comment: It might also make sense to make `n` a double too. And do you know the difference in C++ between 1 and 1.0 ?

Answer (score 2):

[`pow()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/pow) (and [`std::pow()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/pow)) takes 2 input arguments, but you are passing in only 1 value - the result of this calculation:

`(1 + rate_per_period, n) * 0.01`

Because of your use of the [comma operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Built-in_comma_operator), `(1 + rate_per_period, n)` returns `n`, thus the above is *effectively* just this simpler calculation:

`n * 0.01`

That is the sole value you are passing to `pow()`.  But that is not what it wants.

The formula `(1+i)^n-1 / i` does not translate into this code, as you have written it:

`pow((1 + rate_per_period, n) * 0.01)`

It actually translates into code more like this instead:

`pow(1 + rate_per_period, n - 1 / i)`

or:

`pow(1 + rate_per_period, n - 1) / i`

or:

`pow(1 + rate_per_period, n) - 1 / i`

Depending on how you read the formula. However, those solutions are all wrong, because the formulas you have shown are written incorrectly to begin with!  So, you are translating them into C++ code incorrectly.

The correct formula is:

[image: formula]